# Bayesian Network: Calculate probability of a parent node given child node

Tags: probability, statistics, statistical-inference, bayesian, bayesian-network

I have a Question about Bayesian Networks. Given a child node, how to calculate probability of the given parent node(using probability of all nodes).

The bayes net is : [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/LhWQz.png]

I was able to solve for P(E | ¬D ), but how to do it for parent given child ?

How to find P(¬D | E) ?

Comment: You find $P(E)$ and $P(\lnot D)$ and then use Bayes theorem